# Repeated lines with ascending numbers

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code and have been typing code like this repeated times:

```
fmt.Println("Result of test 1:", test1Val/total)
fmt.Println("Result of test 2:", test2Val/total)
fmt.Println("Result of test 3:", test3Val/total)
fmt.Println("Result of test 4:", test4Val/total)
...
```

Seeing as the Numbers are in ascending order, is there a way to repeat a line of code while incrementing the numbers within? (a bit like dragging down a cell in Excel)

EDIT: I'm looking for the VScode function for repeated lines with different values, the code is just an example.

Comment: 98% of situations like this are solved by properly using an array or a map for your values. For the remaining 2% there's code generation of various forms.

Comment: Your question is not clear- are you seeking solution which is code related or you are trying to explore feature of VS Code.

Comment: How does the code generation work?

Comment: @Sandeep the VScode feature, sorry for the unclarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codegeneration is not the answer to your problem.

A stucture similar to this is:

```
testResults := []int{1, 42, 666}
total := 777
for t, result := range testResults {
    fmt.Printf("Result of test %v: %v\n", t, float64(result)/float64(total))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of code generation or arrays, if you still want to write your code or text like that and look for some way of insert incrementing or decrementing sequence of numbers, you can use the vs-code-input-sequence extension and multiple cursors to manipulate and configure the way the sequence is inserted.

Although it's not the best for code efficiency, it's still a very good tool for documentation and other text editing situations. It used the input panel (keyboard shortcut) to insert syntax like, the start, operator, step, digit and radix.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tomoki1207.vscode-input-sequence

Extension credit is to tomoki1207